# Different Python version in jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When I run `!python -V`, in jupyterlab I have Python 3.8.13

When I run `!py -V`, also in jupyter I have this time Python 3.10.7

When I run `python -V` and `py -V` in Powershell I have Python 3.10.7

When I run

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
```

I have `3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Could you tell me why the first one is different from the others?

I think it has to be an issue with conda version but I don't know where it comes from.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JupyterLab is launched from your Conda environment that has Python 3.8.13 installed in it. This is the actual Python version you are running in jupyterlab, and the same version is shown when you type `!python -V`.

You also have a separate non-Conda Python 3.10.7 installation on your system. The `py` command is installed with this Python and is a Python launcher on Windows that works with non-Conda Python installations. The rest of the commands you tried on PowerShell are all outside jupyterlab and use the non-Conda Python version, which is 3.10.7.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple versions of Python installed to your system, e.g. `python -V` and `py -V` use a different one.

The `jupyter` command starts JupyterLab using one of those Python versions. You can see which one by running `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`. If you want to control the Python version used for JupyerLab, then instead of `jupyter lab`, start it as `python -m jupyter lab` or `py -m jupyter lab`. Which one works (either or both) depends on whether JupyterLab is installed for that Python installation.

Similarly, to control the Python version:

- Use `python -m pip ...` or `py -m pip` instead of `pip ...`
- Use `python -m conda ...` or `py -m conda` instead of `conda ...`
- Use `python -m jupyter ...` or `py -m jupyter` instead of `jupyter ...`